# Getting List for Select tag from Map<List<Object>> based on iterator index

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, iterator, ognl

I have a `Map` containing `List`s like below.

```
Map<String,List<Object>> dynamicList = new HashMap <String,List<Object>>();
```

In the above `Map` I have keys like `dynamiclist1`, `dynamiclist5`, `dynamiclist6`, etc.

I have to show this `dynamicList` based on another iterator index like below:

```jsp
<s:iterator value="listOne" var="list" status="stat">
    <s:select name="col%{#stat.index}" 
              listKey="KEY" 
              listValue="VALUE" 
              list="#dynamicList.dynamiclist%{#stat.index}" />
</s:iterator>
```

I want something like this `#dynamicList.dynamiclist%{#stat.index}` to get that list.

Answer (score 0):

When iterating a map via the iterator tag `var` attribute is not necessary, because the current item pushed to the value stack on each iteration. So, referencing `value` attribute of the map entry as a `list` collection.

```
<s:iterator value="listOne" status="stat">
    <s:select name="col%{#stat.index}" 
              listKey="KEY" 
              listValue="VALUE" 
              list="dynamicList['%{top}']" />
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wants to get that select tag list value from dynamicList(another map with keys like dynamiclist1, dynamiclist2, dynamiclist3,..). How can i get that list value from based on my iterator index?

Comment: You don't need iterator index for it, but can try `listOne[%{#stat.index}].value`

Comment: Dear Roman, I don't want listOne list value. I want list from dynamicList(Map<String, List<Object>>).

Comment: then use the iterator `key` value as a key to your another map, what is the `listOne` then? Post the complete code, because it's not clear.

Comment: Dear Romans, i have to create a form dynamically based on listOne. listOne is the List<Object>() which contains information to create textfield tag or select tag. For select tag i have to show List from dynamicList map based on the index value of listOne iterator. This. is my requirement.

Comment: Ok, then use `dynamicList['%{top}']` as a list value.

Comment: i have to append that index value into dynamiclist. Actually i want like this    dynamicList.dynamiclist1 or dynamicList.dynamiclist2

Comment: Populate the the `listOne` list with keys from your second collection, then use that keys to get a proper list.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will try like that and i will update my status.