# Reading contents from application map dynamically IN JSP page. - struts 2.0

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I am using ApplicationAware in my struts 2.0 action class. So, i placed an entry in then application map as

```
application.put("animalDTO", animalDTO);
```

animalDTO:

```
public class AnimalDTO {

    private String name_N1;
    private String name_N2;
    private String name_N3;
    private String name_N4;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Now before going to my jsp page i am populating the values in each of the variables.

In JSP page: i am using iterator to get N1, N2 till N4.
Now i need to create s:textfield and populate these variables content DYNAMICALLY.

ie.

```
<s:iterator value="application.nameList" var="nameList">
    <s:textfield theme="simple" value="%{application.animalDTO.name_#nameList}" />
</s:iterator>
```

Here, i am not getting any values populated.

If i hard code as -> `value="%{application.animalDTO.**name_N1**}"`

Then all the text-fields will be populated with value of name_N1, but that not what i need. I need for fetch the values dynamically.

Can anyone help me with this `OGNL` requirement?
Thanks in advance

=====================

I tried this also, i created string variable which is of the required ognl format, but i dont know how to make the string as a lookup to valuestack. This is what i did:

```
<s:iterator value="application.nameList" var="nameList">
    <s:set var="varUrl" value="%{'application.animalDTO.name_' + #nameList}" />
    <s:property value="varUrl" />
    <s:textfield name="NAME__%{#nameList}" theme="simple" id="NAME-%{#nameList}" value="%{varUrl}" />
</s:iterator>
```

but instead the text box is getting values like:

```
application.animalDTO.name_1
application.animalDTO.name_2
application.animalDTO.name_3
application.animalDTO.name_4
```

what is need is the values corresponding to these variables.

Any idea how to convert this string as an object/key to lookup into valuestack.

Comment: have you tried `#application.nameList` ? also `id`  has been replaced by the var attribute.

Comment: I modified as 
s:iterator value="application.nameList" id="nameListID" var="nameListVar" and value of s:textfield as value="%{application.animalDTO.name_#nameListVar}"
but still not displaying values

Comment: And `var` attribute is not necessary.

Comment: why you still using `application` in your text, since iterator will push the object on top of value stack and in your case object will be `animalDTO` and you can reference properties by referring there name, also class name should start with capital letter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613787/getting-list-for-select-tag-from-maplistobject-based-in-iterator-index/18613787#18617249

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi i put this as a quick example, so missed out the caps of class. Regarding the usage of "application", either way, my requirement is to get the values of properties of animalDTO object by dynamically creating the property name. How can i do that?

Comment: @RomanC here the scenario is different right?, here i already have access to object animalDTO, thats why i am getting the value when i give `value="%{application.animalDTO.name_N1}"`, but i need to create the property name dynamically , ie something like `value="%{application.animalDTO.name_#nameList}"`

Comment: @abyin007 The overall scenario is the same and you could get answers from the question above, unfortunately nobody upvoted them. So, you could yet elaborate on your question.

Comment: i tried my best, still am getting nowhere.. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got the solution. I tried many trail and error methods. And finally hit the answers. We can dynamically read the property values by doing:

```
<s:iterator value="application.nameList" var="nameList">
    <s:textfield theme="simple" value="%{application.animalDTO['name_' + #nameList]}" />
</s:iterator>
```

I tried %{application.**animalDTO['name_' + #nameList]**} and it worked. :-)